# Is there any alternative method to solve Remove character in python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

> Consider two strings s1 and s2,you have to write a static function which takes s1 and s2 strings as arguments and removes the characters from the first string, which are present in the second string. For example, if the first String "India is great" and second String is "in" then the output should be "da s great".

Input Format

> First line should contain string s1. Second line should contain string s2.

```
Constraints

1<=N<=1000

Output Format

Output string

Sample Input 0

    India is great
    in

Sample Output 0

    da s great

Sample Input 1

    Hello all how are you
    are

Sample Output 1

    Hllo ll how you
```

My code

```
lst = [i for i in input()]
check = [i for i in input()]

for i in check:
    for j in lst:
        if i == j or i.upper() == j:
            lst.remove(j)
       
    
for i in lst:
    print(i,end='')
```

**My output**

```
da s great
```

**My output 2 is wrong if are is removed it leaves one extra space**

```
Hllo ll how  you
```

Comment: Why is the `e` and `a` missing from sample output 1?

Comment: Because we need to remove the second input char from the first string

Comment: Side-note: `[i for i in input()]` is a slow, verbose way to write `list(input())`; don't use listcomps when they're neither mapping nor filtering, just use the `list` constructor directly.

Comment: Why are you only checking the uppercase version of `i` but not `j`.  What if `i` is already an uppercase 'A' and j is lowercase 'a'.  The two won't match in that case.  I think you want `if i.upper() == j.upper():`

Comment: the second input is **in** in the first in put India **I** is caps so i have to remove that I also thats why 'if i == j or i.upper() == j:'

Comment: So you don't care if the code doesn't work for other cases than your test cases?  Your code won't work in the reverse case, like for the input `india is great` and `In`.  Can you assume that the user will only enter lowercase in the second input?

Comment: Good question now i get your point. Kindly modify my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just have to replace parts of the string that have two spaces with a single space. The two spaces case will occur when an entire word is deleted.

```
import re

lst = input()
check = [str.lower(c) for c in input()]
upper_check = [str.upper(c) for c in check]

for i in range(len(check)):
      lst = lst.replace(check[i], '')
      lst = lst.replace(upper_check[i], '')

lst = re.sub(r"\s+", ' ', lst)
print(lst.strip())
```

Comment: The space replacement hack won't work if *two* words in a row are deleted; you'll have three adjacent spaces, and the `replace('  ', ' ')` only reduces it to two.

Comment: But it will print I in India but we dont have to print I

Comment: Addressed both of these comments with an edit.

Comment: There's still a case for which this won't get the spaces right...a space left at the beginning or end of the string if the entire first or last word is removed.  You could just call `strip()` on the final result to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You should never modify the list you are looping over.
Instead, you can generate a new string with the forbidden characters not included.
Also to make this algorithmically more efficient, you can store all the forbidden characters in a set.

```
input_s = input() # No need to loop over the lists here.
forbidden_chars = {c.lower() for c in input()}
new_s = ''.join([char in input_s if char.lower() not in forbidden_chars])
print(new_s)
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with extra spaces, which it seems was the OPs primary concern.

Comment: True, although based on the described problem it's not too well defined. e.g. what if the input has consecutive whitespace? If you just want to remove consecutive whitespace, I think `new_s = ' '.join(new_s.split())` should work well.

Answer (score 0):

filter characters in a list comprehension and put the result back together using join:

```
def remove(s1,s2):
    return "".join(c for c in s1 if c.lower() not in s2.lower())
    
print(remove("India is great","in"))
# da s great
```

You can also use translate by building al ist of uppercase and lowercase letters to remove:

```
def remove(s1,s2):
    exclude = str.maketrans("","",s2.lower()+s2.upper())
    return s1.translate(exclude)
```

Removing consecutive spaces can be done by splitting and rebuilding the string:

```
return " ".join(s1.translate(exclude).split())
```

Comment: try this input s1 **Hello all how are you** s2 **are**

Comment: Why do you expect the double spaces to be removed ? Since there are spaces on each side of "are" in s1, it is normal that the result contains two consecutive spaces.  If you need consecutive spaces to be removed you should make that part of the processing rule at the beginning. (i.e. remove characters present in s2 AND consecutive spaces)